# Permission Mode for PWA site using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, permissions, mode

I am trying to create the PWA site using Powershell based on the SharePoint form (basically asking user input such as site name, language, time zone, administrators, permission mode (SharePoint mode vs project mode). I have accomplished everything except assigning the permission mode. I cannot assign permission mode through Powershell. I am on the SharePoint online, so I have to use New-SPOSite -Template pwa#0 command to create the PWA site on SharePoint.

Does anyone know how can I use user input permission mode to assign on the PWA site?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the permission mode using the [Set-SPPProjectPermissionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spprojectpermissionmode?view=sharepoint-ps) cmdlet.

Comment: Please consider adding a relevant code example rather than providing an external link.